# Regular Expression for finding position of a delimiter and removing the text after that in Notepad++ or Ultra Edit

Tags: regex, notepad++, ultraedit

Given a pipe-delimited row:

```
ABC|123|pqr|cde|abc.txt|
```

I have to find 3rd pipe delimiter and remove the rest of the line.

Below is what the result should look like.

```
ABC|123|pqr|
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have anything so far?

Answer (score 3):

Search using below regex and it will capture the first three pipes into group(1):

```
^(.+?\|.+?\|.+?\|).*
```

And then replace it with the captured group.

```
\1
```

Comment: Yo Are simply Awesum...Another enhancement i want to do on it is like as soon as i remove the further text i want to add some text

Comment: @user3443043 You should have tried to figure it out, it's simple really. Just add what you want to add after `\1`...